# I am trying to import data into Archer from an XML file using File Transport data Feed. But no records are getting created

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I am providing XML input as below:

```
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Field>SPH0</Field>
    <Field>Alberta</Field>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

XSLT input in navigation as:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Records">
 <ArcherRecord>
                <Regulator>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Record/Field"/>
                </Regulator>                   
 </ArcherRecord>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

DataFeed gets successfully completed but no records are created. 
I am not able to understand which part I am giving wrong. Like is it XML or XSLT or DataFeed configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shivani, try the following xslt

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns="http://www.archer-tech.com/">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Records">
    <ArcherRecords>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Record" />
    </ArcherRecords>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record" >
    <ArcherRecord>
        <Regulator>
            <xsl:value-of select="Field"/>
        </Regulator> 
    </ArcherRecord>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for response. I had put this in XSLT and the feed got successful but no records are getting created. Do you have any clue on like what could be the probable cause?

Comment: I take it that the fields loaded on the Source Definition tab?  Also, in the data feed, on the Data Map tab, then the Update/Archive tab, is Update and Create checked?

Comment: I have checked create as i didn't want to touch existing records. I have mapped fields as needed. I am doubting for the source definition.

I added source definition by "Add new field" -> "Record" (Parent) -> Field (Child)

Am I mistaken there?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't be adding fields in the Source Field list manually.  Click on the Load Fields link at the top right and select Execute Search for the Schema Source dialog box.  If all goes well the fields will be populated in the Source Fields list.  Then map the fields accordingly on the Data Map Tab.

Comment: Sorry I could not upvote because it says I have less reputation points. I did but it wont show and I approved your answer. Thanks again :)